# Makefile, generate variable based on target name

Tags: variables, makefile

I have the following scenario inside a **Makefile**.

```
METIS_A2_PHP5_FPM = metis-a2-php5-fpm-11 # metis-a2-php5-fpm-12 

all: ganymede metis-a2

box-build:
    @echo ${@} :: $(HOSTNAME) :: $(HOSTIP)
    @echo bash bin/vagrant.sh init $(HOSTNAME) $(HOSTIP)

ganymede:
    @make ganymede-build

ganymede-build: HOSTNAME = "ganymede"
ganymede-build: HOSTIP = "10.0.3.2"
ganymede-build: box-build nis-server.sh syslog-ng-server.sh

metis-a2: metis-a2-php5-fpm # metis-a2-php5

metis-a2-php5-fpm:
    @make metis-a2-php5-fpm-build

metis-a2-php5-fpm-build: $(METIS_A2_PHP5_FPM)

$(METIS_A2_PHP5_FPM):
    @make ${@}-build

metis-a2-php5-fpm-11-build: HOSTNAME = "$(subst -build-host,,${@})"
metis-a2-php5-fpm-11-build: HOSTIP = "10.0.3.$(subst metis-a2-php5-fpm-,,$(HOSTNAME))"
metis-a2-php5-fpm-11-build: box-build apache2-php5-fpm.sh
```

While running **make ganymede** everything goes well and I get the following result:

```
# make ganymede
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/dragosc/Workspace/a1/jupiter'
box-build :: ganymede :: 10.0.3.2
bash bin/vagrant.sh init ganymede 10.0.3.2
ganymede
```

Unfortunately (and this is actually my question), when I run **make metis-a2** or (more specific instruction) **make metis-a2-php5-fpm**, the HOSTNAME and HOSTIP variables are converted from *build-box* target name in stead of the target I need them to be converted from.

```
# make metis-a2
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/dragosc/Workspace/a1/jupiter'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dragosc/Workspace/a1/jupiter'
box-build :: box-build :: 10.0.3.box-build
bash bin/vagrant.sh init box-build 10.0.3.box-build
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dragosc/Workspace/a1/jupiter'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dragosc/Workspace/a1/jupiter'
```

Could you please explain to me why, and also, could you please give me an idea for a fix ?

Many thanks in advance.

NOTE: If something is missing please tell, I'm pulling this from a bigger project.

Comment: Why are you using recursive make here? The only target that needs that at the moment is the `$(METIS_A2_PHP5_FPM):` one and you can avoid that by just using the variable in the prerequisite list again. (Also ` # ....` comments on the end of variables include any spaces before the `#` in the variable value just for the record.)

Comment: The problem here is an evaluation order thing. The target-specific assignments are done immediately so `${@}` and `$(subst)` get expanded immediately and leave you with an empty `HOSTNAME` and a "broken" `HOSTIP`.

Comment: Also your `$(subst)` call uses `-build-host` but you don't use `-host` anywhere else.

Comment: @EtanReisner Sorry for the `-build-host`. I changed a lot the Makefile content and didn't notice it while copying the content here for the question. If you could show me how to do this without recursion I would be very grateful.

Comment: Anytime you have `tgt: ; @make some-other-target` you can replace it with `tgt: some-other-target` (you already have this for some of your targets. But actually doing that here will mean that you can't run more than one of these in the same make run (as make will only execute `box-build`, or any other target, once per-run). Your recursion is making that possible currently.

Comment: @EtanReisner I agree with you and am aware of that. But if you have a target you need executed more than once, that won't work. This fragment here is not from a c/c++ compiling Makefile. It is used for creating vagrant-lxc virtual machines, and I was trying to keep it as clean as possible and not duplicate any piece of code. Don't really know how to tell a target to re-execute ( | (pipe) didn't work ), so I used recursive make.

Comment: Indeed. If you need a target run more than once you need to recurse to cause that to happen. I wouldn't play these target games in that case though I would just use a single recipe with all the various targets listed. Probably assembled into a variable and with per-target variables set as necessary (though I'd probably avoid those in favor of figuring it out from the target name as much as possible).

Answer (score 0):

Discovered a fix for my question, but I am still opened to suggestions, if you guys think there are easier ways.

Instead of passing variables to each target, I'm passing the variables to my recursive make calls. This would work for me (for now); I'm still having issues with another problem (making a target to run recursively) which might also generate problems here (if I drop the recursive make calls).

```
METIS_A2_PHP5_FPM = metis-a2-php5-fpm-11 # metis-a2-php5-fpm-12 

all: ganymede metis-a2

box-build:
    @echo ${@} :: $(HOSTNAME) :: $(HOSTIP)
    @echo bash bin/vagrant.sh init $(HOSTNAME) $(HOSTIP)

ganymede:
    @make ganymede-build HOSTNAME="ganymede" HOSTIP="10.0.3.2"

ganymede-build: box-build nis-server.sh syslog-ng-server.sh

metis-a2: metis-a2-php5-fpm # metis-a2-php5

metis-a2-php5-fpm:
    @make metis-a2-php5-fpm-build

metis-a2-php5-fpm-build: $(METIS_A2_PHP5_FPM)

$(METIS_A2_PHP5_FPM):
    @make ${@}-build HOSTNAME="${@}" HOSTIP="10.0.3.$(subst metis-a2-php5-fpm-,,$(@))"

metis-a2-php5-fpm-11-build: box-build apache2-php5-fpm.sh
```